# Proving that a series converges to zero (involves combinatorial and an alternating sum)

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics

I'm working on this series:

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{i-1}\left|\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^{k+1}\binom{p+q+i+2}{k}\binom{p+q+l-k+1}{p+q}
\frac{(p+1+l-k)^i}{(p+q+i+1)!}\right|$$

where $(p,q)$ are fixed non-negative integers. Computationally, it does decrease:

```
g[p_, q_, i_] := 
 Sum[Abs[Sum[(-1)^(k + 1) Binomial[p + q + i + 2, k] Binomial[
      p + q + l - k + 1, 
      p + q] (p + 1 + l - k)^i/(p + q + i + 1)!, {k, 0, l}]], {l, 0, 
   i - 1}]
f[i_] := N[g[1, 0, i]]
Array[f, 50]

Output= {0.666667, 0.875, 0.341667, 0.161111, 0.129365, 0.123289, \
0.0864446, 0.0859799, 0.065676, 0.0656577, 0.0521962, 0.0521958, \
0.04278, 0.04278, 0.0358899, 0.0358899, 0.0306693, 0.0306693, \
0.0266021, 0.0266021, 0.0233605, 0.0233605, 0.0207277, 0.0207277, \
0.0185547, 0.0185547, 0.0167366, 0.0167366, 0.0151971, 0.0151971, \
0.0138799, 0.0138799, 0.0127427, 0.0127427, 0.0117526, 0.0117526, \
0.0108844, 0.0108844, 0.0101181, 0.0101181, 0.0094377, 0.0094377, \
0.00883025, 0.00883025, 0.00828528, 0.00828528, 0.00779415, \
0.00779415, 0.00734969, 0.00734969}
```

But I don't know what technique might be useful to prove it. I tried to use asymptotic theory by abusing on Stirling's formula and hoping to get the expression asymptotic to a function that goes to zero. But I'm having no luck at it.

Context: From [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tjm/1296483473), I'm trying to estimate the sum

$$\sum_{l=0}^{i-1}|A_{p,q}(l,i-l)-A_{p-1,q+1}(l+1,i-l-1)|$$